# How to list users from all Identity Domains in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I need to retrieve a list of all users present in my Oracle Cloud environment via REST API or Go SDK.

Looking at the [REST API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/iam-domains-rest-api/op-admin-v1-users-get.html), the [Go SDK docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk@v24.3.0+incompatible/identity#IdentityClient.ListUsers), and the [OCI CLI docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.10.4/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/iam/user/list.html), nowhere seems to provide an option to supply Identity Domain as an argument.

`oci iam user list` returns only the set of users present in the "Default" domain, even when I authenticate as a user in another domain.

Is there a way to fetch users from other Identity Domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the REST API doc to list all users in the identity domain:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/iam-domains-rest-api/op-admin-v1-users-get.html

Also, please use the domain URL for the API endpoint? Something like this: https://{domainUrl}/admin/v1/Users).

Unfortunately, we have Go SDK (or other SDKs and CLI) support only for IAM resources but not for Identity Domains (IDCS).

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any documentation of how to create the Authorization header for the IDCS API? I have a header that works for a call to list users via https://identity.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/20160918/users, but doesn't work to list users via the IDCS method linked above

Comment: I was able to create a working Authorization header using the examples found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is an oci-go-sdk with identity domain pkg which can used to list the users associated with a domain associated with a specific compartment.

https://github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/blob/master/identitydomains/list_users_request_response.go

Its requires domain url and the ListUserRequest. Below is the sample code.

```
package oci


import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/example/helpers"
    "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/v65/common"
    "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/v65/identitydomains"
)

 
func InitializeConfigs1() common.ConfigurationProvider {
    customerTenancyId := "**********************" // root compartment ocid
    userOCID := "********************" // user coid
    homeRegion := "us-ashburn-1". // region
    fingerprint := "******************"
    key := "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
*******************************
----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
    cp := common.NewRawConfigurationProvider(customerTenancyId, userOCID, homeRegion, fingerprint, key, nil)
    return cp
}
 
func ListDomainUsers() {
    cp := InitializeConfigs1()
    ExampleListUsers_ListUsers_IdentityDomain(cp)
}
 
func ExampleListUsers_ListUsers_IdentityDomain(cp common.ConfigurationProvider) {
    // build the url
    //endpoint := "https://****************" // Domain url
 
    client, err := identitydomains.NewIdentityDomainsClientWithConfigurationProvider(cp, endpoint)
 
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
 
    // List domain users
    req := identitydomains.ListUsersRequest{}
    resp, err := client.ListUsers(context.Background(), req)
 
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
 
    fmt.Println(resp)
 
    // list domain groups
    grpReq := identitydomains.ListGroupsRequest{}
    resp1, err1 := client.ListGroups(context.Background(), grpReq)
 
    helpers.FatalIfError(err1)
 
    fmt.Println(resp1)
}
```

Here is the bash documentation for reference.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.27.0/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/identity-domains/users/list.html

Answer (score 0):

https://kaamilant.com/change-oracle-cloud-username/

you can use same API with get action and it will return list of all users from a single identity domain. if you have multiple identity domains, you can develop a script in postman to iterate one by one